# Retain dialogArguments between postbacks

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am currently creating a page that is accessed via the custom url functionality. Whenever my page does a post-back to the server I lose the `window.dialogArguments` property therefore losing the ability to access `getFields()`, `container.deleteField()` etc.

Is there any way around this?

My first thought was to do all communication with the server via `XMLHttpRequest` calls, that would get rid of the post-back issue but the problem is the code (from Tridion 5.3) relies heavily on server side logic and its going to be a big job to change it. (5.3 seems to use `window.returnValue` rather than `dialogArguments`.

My second thought was maybe I could use some value in `window.opener`, but I am unable to find the property/function that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the post-back in a separate iframe. That will keep the main window alive and thus keep the `window.dialogArguments` accessible to your code.

From what I know the `window.opener` should survive any post-back. So I'm not sure what you are looking for there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the iframe post-back solution tomorrow and update.

Comment: I don't really know what I was looking for in the `window.opener` either. Having my aspx page within an iFrame works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5 or later, you can also simply wrap your controls in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).

It will then automatically do the postbacks in asynchronous client-side requests instead, so the window will not be reloaded.